# Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

I am busy with [Laravel From Scratch: Updating Records and Eager Loading](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10). I have followed the tut but I am getting this error when trying to add user data in CardsController. I am assuming that I've missed a step in the card user relationship somewhere but I've watched the video 3 times and my database queries for User, Card & Note matches the video exactly.

Is there another step I need to perform after creating the Users table via the migration perhaps?

**Error**

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345:
```

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()

**CardsController code**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Card;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CardsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $cards = Card::all();
        return view('cards.index', compact('cards'));
    }

    public function show(Card $card)
    {
        $card = Card::with('notes.user')->get();
        return $card;
        return view('cards.show', compact('card'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `note` model is lacking the relationship definition for it's associated `user`, it looks like.

You should just be able to add the relationship in the `Notes` model like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Ohgodwhy, I got the same error when I call a User model method. How can I solve it?

Comment: @user2356198 Consider asking a new question with a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you should get a great response.

Comment: @Solivan You should make a question so we can vet it there, this has been answered and your situation may be a bit more unique.

Answer (score 1):

That video does have some problems, so I also encountered the same problem.
You should just be able to add the relationship in the Note model like this:

```
public function user()
{
    //return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

and in the User model like this:

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\Note');
}
```

bless you !

Comment: It looks like you just need to switch **belongsTo** to **hasMany** type of relationship in your **User** model. Changing of string class providing or via PHP has no effect: **Note::class** equal to **'App\Note'** in your case.