# Laracasts tutorial: Is method 'Latest()' removed?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Is the method "latest" used in Controllers removed in newest version of Laravel?

In PHP Storm I get follow error: 
Method latest() not found in App/Thread.

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $threads = Thread::latest()->get();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }
```

I'm following a LaraCasts tutorial, and browsing to said page gives me following error. -> forum.test/threads.

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::path does not exist. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\forum\resources\views\threads\index.blade.php)

As per requested, my view: it is in resources/views/threads/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Forum Threads</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @foreach ($threads as $thread)
                            <article>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="{{ $thread->path() }}">
                                        {{ $thread->title }}
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="body">{{ $thread->body }}</div>
                            </article>
                            <hr/>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Also, my routes.

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('threads', 'ThreadController');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Disclose view code as well I bet, you are doing another query calls in there and it blows up on you.

Comment: I just started .It's my first Controller - and first function (index) . So I just trying to figure out what is wrong. - more detail here, Latest posted Question @  https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/2

Comment: Show the view, without it we can not help you.

Comment: So now as you can see `<a href="{{ $thread->path() }}">` is the problem, if path is an attribute in your model you need to use `$thread->path` instead.

Comment: Thanks path did the trick . :)

Comment: You need to learn how to read exceptions / errors: `ErrorException (E_ERROR) Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::path does not exist.` So right away go and search for `path` string in `views\threads\index.blade.php`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest this willl help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to the code you posted. `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::path does not exist.`. You are calling somewhere `path` method which does not exist.

To answer your question, method `latest()` is still present in the (currently) newest version of Laravel 5.6:
https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_latest

My guess would be you have an incorrect config of the `Thread` model relationships. Most probably you did not define `path()` relationship.

See this answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934093/1885946

Comment: There is nothing written in app/Thread.php besides default code.

Comment: Actually the error was I used a later version of index.blade.php , where path is a added in Thread.php. I tried to write down all steps of the tutorial, and accidentally wrote wrong version. 

Solution: I changed path() to path and now all works again. :)